# PC Boots then writes giant datastore.edb file slowing the computer down

Tags: windows-7

The system that I'm looking at is Windows 7, 32bit.

When the system boots up it spends a ton of time reading and writing to the DataStore.edb file which is located in Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore directory.  This makes the system run really slow for several minutes, probably about 10 if I'm honest.  If you stop the Windows Update service, within a minute the system will stop reading and writing from the file and everything runs smoothly.

Things I've tried:

I've stopped Windows Update, deleted the file, rebooted, but when I do that Windows rebuilds the file until it's a few hundred MB in size.  Once Windows is happy with whatever it's doing, it stops and my disk usage and cue drop down to normal levels and the system does whatever you want with plenty of speed.

I've booted into SafeMode and run several virus scans and Kaspersky's RootKit killer tool and nobody finds anything offensive.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 27):

I know it's way past the point of being able to provide a suitable solution for you now, but I have exactly the same thing with a Windows 7 machine at work. For future reference, you can always check the integrity of (`/g`) and/or defrag (`/d`) *.edb files with `esentutl.exe`.

e.g. `esentutl.exe /d c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb`

If you are unable to run this command with "-1032" error, you can boot into safemode (without networking) and run the command from there. You might first need to run it with the /p switch to repair file corruption.

Comment: I tried this and I received the following message:

Error: Access to source database 'c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Data
Store.edb' failed with Jet error -1032.

Comment: @Alf47 Stop the Windows Update service and try again

Comment: @Alf47 You need to run Command Prompt as administrator to have access.

Comment: And it is "c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Data**Store**.edb". No space!

Answer (score 14):

[RAMMap](https://superuser.com/questions/437918/how-do-i-find-whats-eating-up-all-of-my-systems-memory-not-superfetch) showed that `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb` mapped file was wasting 400 Mb of my precious RAM.
Moreover Windows Update was constantly slowing down the system in process of updating that huge file.

`esentutl.exe` just reduced `DataStore.edb` size from slightly more than 600 Mb to slightly less that 600 MB and proved to be useless in my case.

http://juneyourtech.blogspot.com/2013/06/datastoreedb-and-windows-vista.html states that deleting this file is also not an option as Windows Update would rebuild it to the same size of next run.

So I had to completely [disable](https://superuser.com/questions/460076/disable-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line) Windows Update Service autorun. This greatly lowered waste of RAM, CPU and disk IO. 
The system is much more responsive now.

See also [How to schedule download of windows 7 updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/480920/how-to-schedule-download-of-windows-7-updates) for a way to launch update using Windows Task Scheduler.

**Update**

Take a look also at [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/996072#996072)

Comment: BTW, after free update to Windows 10 on the same old hardware the problem didn't reproduce.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding upon @mafbailey 's answer (And a big thanks to you, as well!) make sure to open the command prompt as an administrator when utilizing the following command line action to have the appropriate file permissions.

I'd have been stuck had I not known =)

```
esentutl.exe /d c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
```

Comment: Also stop Windwos update services from 900Mb => 898MB

Comment: An inferior copy of an existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same problem with a slowly starting computer running w7 home edition. Opening email or firefox was frustrating.

On my computer, during start up, the **anti virus program** (windows essentials) **seemed to be taking a lot of time** on the `datastore.edb` file.

This **[link about
*"Improve PC Performance and Stability by Properly Configuring Anti-Virus"*](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/improve-pc-performance-stability-anti-virus-exclusions/)**
 solved the slow start up problem for me.

The solution basically involves telling the virus scanner (windows essentials) to **exclude checking this file**. 
I did the other exclusions on the windows files as well. (but i'm fine with the scanners checking my photos, even though they should be safe)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Windows Update KB3050265](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265), released 2nd June 2015.

This is optional so you may have to look for it in Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Update > Show all available updates > Optional, and manually install it.

Comment: This didn't help, I already have that update and still wake-up from hibernation is slow, and restart even much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing Windows Update, this method is for Windows 7

Go to Programs \ Accessories: Cmd prompt

Click the right mouse button and run as administrator.

In the prompt window follow the sequence below:

net stop wuauserv (after Enter)

net stop bits (after Enter)

In Windows Explorer:

Go to the folder windows\software distribution\download (delete everything in there)

Go to the folder windows\software distribution\DataStore (delete everything in there)

Go to the folder windows\software distribution\DataStore\Logs (delete everything in there)

Go to the folder windows\software distribution\PostRebootEventCache (delete everything in there)

The CMD prompt window:

net start wuauserv (after Enter)

net start bits (after Enter)

Sources:- http://tecnicoinformaticacuritiba.com.br/corrigindo-windows-update/ / https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d75e92b9-4caf-425d-b841-0bae79f7adf1/windows-7-windows-update-no-funciona?forum=winvistapt

Comment: As others have shown here and at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f5744a18-d4ca-4631-8324-878b9225251d/windowssoftwaredistribution-folder-cleanup-automation?forum=winserverwsus, this doesn't solve anything and only slows down the machine while Windows Update fully rebuilds the database.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new WindowsUpdate Client Update to fix the slow Update searching/Installation.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

This updates reduces the detection time and uses less RAM. So try it out

Comment: warning: after installing this, Windows Update now does not work at all, it immediately gives error `"WindowsUpdate_80244019" "WindowsUpdate_dt000"` which I've been unable to solve

Comment: Uninstalling this update did return me to the previous situation I was in

Comment: @M.M error 80244019 means WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND Same as HTTP status 404 - the server cannot find the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). which av suite/firewall do you use?

Comment: MS Security Essentials, and no firewall . Rest of internet was working fine (including IE)

Comment: @M.M try at least the June 2015 version which first includes the memory usage fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this says that I posted this in January 2013, this problem was only a few months ago in 2015.  Ha!

Anyway - I'm sorry to waste everyone's time.  For some reason I wasn't getting notifications about this thread until today, December 9, 2015.

I tried a number of things and ended up on the phone with the manufacturer of the device that this computer was within.  It turns out that they have a bug in their implementation of Windows that causes this to happen.  The only solution to the problem is to re-image the machine and hope it doesn't happen again.

This applies to Zeiss OCT machines for those who are wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems.
I installed **KB3050265** from the website and it solved all these problems.
 Make sure you install the correct version for your Windows ( 64 bit (x64) or 32-bit (x86))